# how many maximum no. of channels in an audio file we can create with FFMPEG amerge filter?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

how many maximum no. of channels in an audio file we can create with FFMPEG amerge filter?

We have a requirement to merge multiple single channel audio files into multi channel single audio file.

Each channel represents the speaker in the audio file.

I tried amerge filter and could do it upto 8 files. I am getting blank audio file when I try to do it for 10 audio files, and I think the FFMPEG amerge filter command doesn't produce any error either.

Can I create N no. of multi-channel audio files with N no. of files? Here N may be 100+? Is it possible?

I am new to this audio api etc. so any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how many maximum no. of channels in an audio file we can create with FFMPEG amerge filter? We have a requirement to merge multiple single channel audio files into multi channel single audio file.

Max inputs is **64**. According to `ffmpeg -h filter=amerge`:

```
inputs <int> ..F.A...... specify the number of inputs (from 1 to 64) (default 2)
```

Or look at the source code at `libavfilter/af_amerge.c` and refer to `SWR_CH_MAX`.

> Can I create N no. of multi-channel audio files with N no. of files? Here N may be 100+? Is it possible?

Chain multiple amerge filters with a max of 64 inputs per filter. Or use the amix filter that has a max of 32767.

Comment: That range is misleading. Ultimately the total number of channels across all inputs must not exceed 64. So that's e.g. 64 mono inputs or 32 stereo inputs.

Comment: @Gyan OP mentioned "single channel audio files" so for simplicity in this case I did not elaborate the inputs/channels distinction.

Comment: The OP mentioned N may be 100+, and you suggested daisy-chaining amerges, so they will run into it then.

Comment: Thank you very much Gyan and llogan, this was really helpful.